# Converting Client Side binding to Server Side to improve performance

Tags: c#, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a `window` that renders 5 `Telerik grids` using client side binding via `AJAX` calls to controller. Given that the data is not enough for a paging solution, I want to cut down the loading time of few of the grids, which at max reaches upto 2.5 seconds.

Following is the sample code for one of the grid which uses client-side binding:

```
<h4> EMP List</h4>
    @{
        Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.EMPList)
        .Name("gvEMPList")
        .DataKeys(keys =>
        {
            keys.Add(t => t.empID);
        })
        .Columns(columns =>
        {

            columns.Bound(s => s.EMPName).Title("NAME").ReadOnly().Width(150);

            columns.Bound(s => s.EMPType).Title("Type")
                 .ClientTemplate("<# if(EMPTypeIDOld==EMPTypeID)) { #> <#= EMPType #> <#} else { #> <span style='color:#929292'> [<#=EMPTypeOld #>] </span> <# } #>")
                 .ReadOnly().Width(350);
            if (ViewBag.EMP_Edit)
            {
                columns.Bound(s => s.empID).Title("Action").Width(230)
                         .ClientTemplate("<# if(empID <= 0) { #> <input type='button' class='t-button' value='Reject Salaray' onclick=\"gvSalaryRequest('<#= empID#>')\"/> <# } #>").ReadOnly();
            }

        })
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
            .Select("_SelectEMPToRequest", "Employee", new { DeptID = ViewBag.DeptID})
            )

        .Sortable()
            //.Scrollable(s => s.Height("auto"))
       .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
       .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
       .ColumnContextMenu()
       .Render();
    }
```

The primary concern is of having as many AJAX calls as grids in the page.

### Questions:

- Should I consider `Server-Side` binding for this?
- If yes, How do I achieve the same functionality as above? (e.g.
  clientTemplate, HTMLembedding, Custom command).
- Is there any other solution to be considered?

Comment: Is your ajax calls using same or different data? If data is different I consider using ajax calls because of its parallel nature and early page loading.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your view or requirement. But I had a similar issues  and I used tab to overcome this. Users are not going to see all the grid at same time. So I'm getting data on tab activate.

If you can't use tab then server side grid is right way to go about it.